# List `k` words starting with a fixed prefix in descending order of their frequency

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures, trie, n-gram

I have a list of around `10^5` English words and their initial frequency. I want to write a word completion suggestion program that will return a list of maximum `k` words, starting with a given prefix, sorted in descending order of their frequency. The data structure should also be able to update the frequency count of a word by 1(Whenever a word is used).

For example-
Given 'engin' as prefix, and `k = 3`, it should return a list like this-
{ {17, "engine"}, {10, "engineer"}, {4, "engineering"} }

The value of `k` should be within [1, 15].

`Trie` data structure should have been enough if sorting by frequency wasn't a concern, but it is. Can anybody hint me on any data structure or any approach to solve this problem?

Note : `Trie` data structure consumes too much space. Seems like I can't afford over `10MB` for this data structure. Plus, if I use max heaps associated with trie nodes(at least upto 3/4 depth) the memory consumption becomes HUGE.

For now I've tried this-
Maintain 4 sorted sets(of pointers, pointing to the strings).
Set `i` is list of pointers to strings of `string length >= i` sorted-

- Lexicographical order of first `i` letters of the string
- If clash, in descending order of frequency
- If clash again, in any order(insignificant)

This works well, considering, I require O(4n*log2(n)) time and O(n*log2(n)) space for initialization. For each query, I have a lookup time complexity of O(log2(n)), plus a traversal of at most approximately 100 words in worst case. For updating the frequency of a word, O(8*log2(n)) time is required.

Comment: A simple DB query is not fast enough? Also, instead of updating the frequencies immediately you could do that e.g. once a day to reorganize the search structure.

Comment: @Henry No, I need a much faster solution, preferably using a in memory data structure.

Comment: Have you considered want a max-heap?

Answer (score 1):

This could be done with combination of two data structures: trie and segment tree. (If dictionary is static and `k` is not very large).

After constructing trie for your dictionary, augment each trie node with indices of the first/last word belonging to this node. For example, node 'engin' could store index 1001 for "engine" and index 1003 for "engineering".

When searching for a list of `k` words, start with searching given prefix in the trie. Then use first/last word indices to perform `k` range maximum queries. After each query temporarily set frequency count of found word to `-1`.

Use segment tree data structure for range maximum queries. (See [tutorial at TopCoder](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=lowestCommonAncestor#Range_Minimum_Query_%28RMQ%29) for details).

This approach allows to handle each query in time O(prefix_size + k * log(dict_size)). Counter updates need O(log(dict_size)) time. Initial frequencies are loaded in O(dict_size) time.

---

Other alternative is to store a sorted array of `k_max` {counter, index} pairs in each node of the trie.

Initial frequencies should be updated with merge at each node in bottom-up order (with DFS) in O(k_max * dict_size) time. Each counter update needs O(k_max * word_length) time. Top-k queries are served in O(prefix_size) time. Downside is much higher memory requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Why not a trie? You can use an extra data field for the counter and add a sort algorithm to the search algorithm. Updating the  counter and the trie is also fast. If you only want the k maximum/top edges then it's faster because you don't need to sort all.

Comment: Case where it's not very effective : for example, I want suggestion for prefix `'a'` and `k = 10`. Although I need only 10 suggestions, a trie in that case must traverse all the words that start with `a`, to build the list, which is a huge portion of the tree.

Comment: If you only want the k top edges from a it's faster then to sort all egdes!!

Comment: @user1362452: In your case, with 10^5 words, your result set of words that start with 'a' will be smaller than 10^4. And although you have to *traverse* them, you don't have to store them. You can build a max-heap of 10, and keep only the 10 words that have the highest frequency. Your selection algorithm becomes O(n log k), where `n` is the number of words that start with the prefix, and `k` is the number of words you want to select. Assuming that updates are infrequent in comparison to queries, this is a very efficient way to go. And it's easy to implement.

Comment: @JimMischel I've updated my question. Space complexity is a concern. Would you kindly take a look at my current solution and suggest any improvement?